# Generics: why won't this compile?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Given the following code:

```
class A<T>
{
  internal void Add(T obj) { }
}

class C { }

class B<T> where T : C
{
  public B()
  {
    A<T> a = new A<T>();
    a.Add(new C());
  }
}
```

The call to `Add` does not compile. It does when I cast it to `T` first:

```
a.Add((T)new C());
```

It might be the sleep deprivation, but what am I missing here?

If `T` is of type `C` (note the constraint on `B`), then why isn't `A<T>` equivalent to `A<C>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if B were declared with a type of D, which would be a class which extends C, then adding a new C would violate the type.

Comment: But only if this weren't .NET 4 with contravariance for D and C in B.

Comment: FYI, the new variance features only apply to delegate and interface types constructed with reference types.

Answer (score 3):

because T could be a subclass of C.

you can't add a Animal bob = new Fish() to a List<Giraffe>

Answer (score 2):

`A.Add()` is expecting a `T`.  You're giving it a `C`.  This is okay as long as the compiler knows that a `C` is a `T`.

But that's not what your constraint says.  It only says that a `T` is a `C`, which is the opposite.

Comment: I find your explanation much easier to parse than Yishai's.